# XSLT - group XML data

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I am trying to convert XML to a particular XML format by grouping 2 `<element>` nodes into one `<item>`. Then repeat the format foreach `<element>`. I would like blank nodes if there isn't date to fill them. Example would be at the very bottom of the desired result. Notice the last three nodes are empty.

My XML

```
<feed version="2.4">
<list>
    <element>
        <field name="01">text1</field>
        <field name="02">text2</field>
        <field name="03">text3</field>
        <field name="04">text4</field>
    </element>
    <element>
        <field name="01">text5</field>
        <field name="02">text6</field>
        <field name="03">text7</field>
        <field name="04">text8</field>
    </element>
    <element>
        <field name="01">text9</field>
        <field name="02">text10</field>
        <field name="03">text11</field>
        <field name="04">text12</field>
    </element>
    <element>
        <field name="01">text13</field>
        <field name="02">text14</field>
        <field name="03">text15</field>
        <field name="04">text16</field>
    </element>
    <element>
        <field name="01">text17</field>
        <field name="02">text18</field>
        <field name="03">text19</field>
        <field name="04">text20</field>
    </element>
</list>
```

Desired result

```
<item>
   <title1>text1</title1>
   <desc1>text2</desc1>
   <opt1>text3</opt1>
   <title2>text5</title2>
   <desc2>text6</desc2>
   <opt2>text7</opt2>
</item>
<item>
   <title1>text9</title1>
   <desc1>text10</desc1>
   <opt1>text11</opt1>
   <title2>text13</title2>
   <desc2>text14</desc2>
   <opt2>text15</opt2>
</item>
<item>
   <title1>text17</title1>
   <desc1>text18</desc1>
   <opt1>text19</opt1>
   <title2></title2>
   <desc2></desc2>
   <opt2></opt2>
</item>
```

The XSLT im using. Im getting hung up on getting the next values for title2, desc2, opt2.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="feed/list/element">
        <xsl:if test="not(number()=0) and position() mod 2 = 0">
           <Item>
               <title1><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='01']"/></title1>
               <desc1><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='02']"/></desc1>
               <opt1><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='03']"/></opt1>
               <title2><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='01']"/></title2>
               <desc2><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='02']"/></desc2>
               <opt2><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='03']"/></opt2>
       </Item>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I updated the question with what im working with right now. Im working to grab the next set of values based off my `position()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/feed">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="list/element[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <item>
                <title1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='01']"/>              
                </title1>
                <desc1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='02']"/>              
                </desc1>
                <opt1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='03']"/>              
                </opt1>
                <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::element[1]" />
                <title2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$next/field[@name='01']"/>                
                </title2>
                <desc2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$next/field[@name='02']"/>                
                </desc2>
                <opt2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$next/field[@name='03']"/>                
                </opt2>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```